# XAMPP - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'users'

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Awhile back I deleted and messed around with some functions in XAMPP.

I reinstalled it and moved/renamed my folder with all my other files so I now have a new xampp directory that's empty and fresh.

But when I try to use any database functionality it gives me error(s) like the one below:

```
SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'users'
```

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar error `SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_table_uiprefs'`. I solved it by opening up `config.inc.php` in the PHPMyAdmin root folder and commenting out the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';`

Comment: above answer solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The user has not been given privileges to read the tables.

When creating an user for the database through the cpanel of your host, you can give the user the privileges.

Or read this documentation to do it through MySql command,

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Do you know why the userid before the @-sign is empty?

Answer (score 1):

you can solve through Enabling the  use of SELECT

GRANT SELECT ON db.table TO 'user'@'localhost';

or

> Grant all on db.table to 'user'@'localhost';

Answer (score 0):

I've just gave the access to the added user, to use `phpMyAdmin` database, and it works perfectly:

```
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT ON phpmyadmin.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the user before the at sign being empty was key to figuring out the problem.

I had an account `''@localhost` (it showed up at `<anonymous>@localhost` in mysqladmin) that mysql was logging me into instead of the user I requested. This is because mysql selects your user based on some logic and not the requested user name alone.

Deleting the anonymous user fixed the problem.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. If you create an account for a user that applies to all hosts (e.g. myuser@'%') and an anonymous user exists for localhost (''@localhost), then the anonymous account will be used when connecting locally as myuser, rather than the myuser@'%' account. You either need to create a separate myuser@localhost set of privileges, or modify/delete the anonymous account settings. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html.