# phpMyAdmin configuration storage issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm well aware that this is a commonly asked question, and I've gone through countless posts here, and elsewhere, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I am seeing this error:

`The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated.`

This is my configuration file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
```

There is a user called PMA with no password and full permissions.

I have a database called phpmyadmin, and it was populated with the tables generated in the `examples/create_tables.sql` script.  I cannot browse to these tables and see the contents, however because `SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma__table_uiprefs'` (I am logged into the root user).

The query phpMyAdmin tries to run when I try to access any of the configuration tables is:

```
SELECT  `prefs` 
FROM  `phpmyadmin`.`pma__table_uiprefs` 
WHERE  `username` =  'root'
AND  `db_name` =  'phpmyadmin'
AND  `table_name` =  'pma__bookmark'
```

I have cleared by browsers cache, restarted apache, done all of the little tricks I've seen elsewhere but all that's doing is making me frustrated.

Comment: the second error message you provided, "SELECT command denied" suggests you are not being recognized as 'root'.  Can you clarify what action you took that generated the error?  e.g. what command did you enter, how did you try to 'browse to these tables'?

Comment: @Ryan I'm not actually performing any command, but I get this error if I try to navigate to one of the tables in phpmyadmin.  I edited the post with the query phpMyAdmin tries to run.

Comment: I understand now, you are logged into phpmyadmin's web interface as 'root', then you click on 'databases', then 'phpmyadmin', then 'pma__table_uiprefs' and you get your error, is that correct?  Your question seems environment specific, it would help to understand what OS, phpmyadmin version... are you using XAMPP, cpanel, etc.  Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376637/xampp-select-command-denied-to-user-localhost-for-table-users

Comment: I am using LAMP on Ubuntu Server 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of frustration, I removed LAMP & phpmyadmin and reinstalled them.  After the setup I was greeted without the error message.  Don't know why this was happening but reinstalling it fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution is to follow the steps suggested by `phpmyadmin` itself:

**Step 1:** click **find out why** link
[image: step 1]

**Step 2:** click **create** link to create a database named *phpmyadmin*
[image]

**Step 3:** (actually nothing to do in this step)
[image]

**I don't know why no one said anything about it!**

Comment: it's made to make as it is.... 
programatically made to be like that or eventually will be like that.
*with purpose from the origin developers*

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue and I didn't have to reinstall LAMP, purging and reinstalling phpmyadmin only was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today (April 9, 2014)after an upgrade to 4.1.12deb2
The actual issue causing multiple error-messages was the definition in the php-code of phpmyadmin in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config/setup.forms.php

The table names are defined there with a prefix consisting of two underscores `(pma__)`, but the actual tables have just the prefix of: `pma_` (one underscore).

So renaming all the tables solved the matter. In overview of database phpmyadmin, click 'check all' and then |with selected| 'replace table prefix'. And then entering `pma_` (1 underscore) and `pma__` (2 underscores). Works like a charm.

Comment: Tried adding the double underscore and didn't work for me, might need to go with the heavier handed method of full reinstall of LAMP.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your `controluser` (`pma`) does not have necessary privileges. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/QA_4_0/setup.html#using-authentication-modes

Comment: I ran `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pma'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` just to see, and no this did not solve my problem.